# Cómo puedo insertar un valor de tipo String pero que tenga espacios? por ejemplo: quiero insertar el modelo de celular P20 Lite

Tags: java

```
        ***Cómo defino aquí el String para que me 
        acepte "P20 Lite" o cualquier modelo que lleve un espacio?***
```

1. Elemento de lista

   ```
       System.out.println("Qué marca es?");
       Marca = sc.next();                
       System.out.println("Qué modelo es?");
       Modelo = sc.next();
       System.out.println("Cuánto cuesta?");
       Precio = sc.nextInt();
   ```

Comment: Usa la funcion nextLine ejemplo http://javacodebasics.blogspot.com/2013/03/diferencia-entre-next-y-nextline-en-java.html

Comment: el usuario @permomo te pregunta: ¿estás pidiendo los datos por consola?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes hacer uso del método nextLine() de la clase Scanner como te muestro a continuación:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String marca = scanner.nextLine();
```

Si necesitas más información acerca de esta clase puedes revisar la documentación oficial de Java en https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html